# Why the user-defined conversion function template cannot have a deduced return type?

Tags: c++

What is the reason of the following rule, "a user-defined conversion function template cannot have a deduced return type."

```
struct S {
  operator auto() const { return 10; } // OK
  template<class T> operator auto() const { return 42; } // error
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if it was allowed, in the second line, there is nothing that depends on the template. 
It can't be called (what is the purpose of `T` in that case ?)

If you want to convert to a user defined type, then you'll do that:
Let's say you have:

```
struct S
{
   template<typename T> operator T() { return T(42); }
};
```

That's clear and there is no need to deduce anything.
You'd call this like this:

```
S s;
int v = s;
float f = s;
```

Please notice that, in that case, using `auto` instead of `float` in the code above would prevent the compiler to deduce the type (is it a `float` ? an `int` ? an `Orange` ?). The sentence above simply explains that.