# Combined with C++23 Deducing this and conversion operator with auto return type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-deduction, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

I recently noticed a strange issue regarding C++23 *Deducing this* feature.

Suppose we have a struct `S` with a simple conversion operator:

```
struct S {
  operator int() { return 42; }
};

int i = S{};
```

Since `42` is of type `int`, we can specify the return type of the conversion operator as `auto`, for example:

```
struct S {
  operator auto() { return 42; }
};

int i = S{};
```

This is [totally fine](https://godbolt.org/z/4EY5hzWzT). If we apply C++23 *Deducing this* feature on it, it would be:

```
struct S {
  operator auto(this S) { return 42; }
};

int i = S{};
```

This is [totally fine](https://godbolt.org/z/Tjv1e6YMo) too. However, when I replace `this S` with `this auto`:

```
struct S {
  operator auto(this auto) { return 42; }
};

int i = S{};
```

[**All three compilers reject the above code**](https://godbolt.org/z/xE5K8jdEx). GCC gives:

```
<source>:5:9: error: cannot convert 'S' to 'int' in initialization
    5 | int i = S{};
```

However, when I change the return type of the conversion operator back to `int`, then all [three compilers compile fine](https://godbolt.org/z/baf176qbr):

```
struct S {
  operator int(this auto) { return 42; }
};

int i = S{};
```

This confuses me.

Why does the compiler reject `operator auto(this auto) { return 42; }`? I see no reason to reject it as it seems intuitive to me. So I'm wondering what does the standard say about this? Or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the user-defined conversion function template cannot have a deduced return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889615/why-the-user-defined-conversion-function-template-cannot-have-a-deduced-return-t)

Comment: @Alan no this does not answer the question being asked here. In the Q&A you propose as duplicate OPs code has a template argument that cannot be deduced and the answer argues based on that. The answer is even wrong with respect to that. It claims it would be impossible to call the operator because tempalte arguments cannot be deduced, but thats a faulty argument. Anyhow, almost nothing in that answer is relevant for the question asked here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [CWG1878](https://wg21.link/CWG1878).

[[class.conv.fct]p9](https://wg21.link/class.conv.fct#9):

> A conversion function template shall not have a deduced return type.

`operator auto(this auto)` is an abbreviated function template, so it is not valid.

The reason it was disallowed is that it was of limited use at the time and I think GCC had a very difficult time with naming this function (See also: [CWG1670](https://wg21.link/CWG1670))

You see the same behaviour for something like this:

```cpp
template<int = 0>
operator auto() { return 42; }
```

Comment: While your answer seems correct, it seems it is kind of a defect in the language. While you could argue that `this auto` makes it a template, there is a big difference compared to the template function described in CWG1670: in the latter the template argument can not be deduced, but `this auto` can be.